# Insert HTML5 context menu entry at the bottom

Tags: html, greasemonkey

I try to add entries to the context menu of the browser for a greasemonkey script. The code below works fine, however, I'd like to have my custom entries at the bottom of the menu instead at the top, because I think it breaks the workflow.

```
<div contextmenu="userscript-TEST">
    <menu id="userscript-TEST" type="context">\
        <menuitem id="userscript-TEST-ENTRY" label="TEST ENTRY"></menuitem>\
    </menu>
</div>
```

Here is the code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yjgygxgf/4/

EDIT: I think this example only works in Firefox at the moment.